# Jenkins thinBackup back up .properties files?

Tags: jenkins

We are using thinBackup (1.73) on our Jenkins for Windows (1.53x) and the backups appear to be working properly.  I then have a daily Jenkins job that copies the output to the NAS.
Our Jenkins jobs use .properties files in their respective jobs directory for things such as source control, etc which don't get backed up as part of the thinBackup job.  So, when running through a restore scenario, obviously jobs are now incomplete.  Is there a way to get thinBackup to back up other files within the respective jobs directories?

Answer (score 0):

The [SCM Sync Configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) looks like a better option, as it allows you to specify [additional user-defined files](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+Config+shared+additionnal+includes) to back up.